# Pass-through for IAsyncEnumerable?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, iasyncenumerable

I'd like to know if there's a way I can write a function to "pass through" an IAsyncEnumerable... that is, the function will call another IAsyncEnumerable function and yield all results without having to write a `foreach` to do it?

I find myself writing this code pattern a lot. Here's an example:

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<string> MyStringEnumerator();

async IAsyncEnumerable<string> MyFunction()
{
   // ...do some code...

   // Return all elements of the whole stream from the enumerator
   await foreach(var s in MyStringEnumerator())
   {
      yield return s;
   }
}
```

For whatever reason (due to layered design) my function `MyFunction` wants to call `MyStringEnumerator` but then just yield everything without intervention. I have to keep writing these `foreach` loops to do it. If it were an `IEnumerable` I would return the `IEnumerable`. If it were C++ I could write a macro to do it.

What's best practice?

Comment: Does your `...do some code...` call `yield return` at all? Does it `await`?

Comment: What do you have inside `MyStringEnumerator()`?

Comment: Why not just `return MyStringEnumerator();`  ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> If it were an IEnumerable I would return the IEnumerable.

Well, you can just do the same thing with `IAsyncEnumerable` (note that the `async` is removed):

```
IAsyncEnumerable<string> MyFunction()
{
 // ...do some code...

 // Return all elements of the whole stream from the enumerator
 return MyStringEnumerator();
}
```

However, there's an important semantic consideration here. When calling an enumerator method, the `...do some code...` will be executed *immediately*, and *not* when the enumerator is enumerated.

```
// (calling code)
var enumerator = MyFunction(); // `...do some code...` is executed here
...
await foreach (var s in enumerator) // it's not executed here when getting the first `s`
  ...
```

This is true for both synchronous and asynchronous enumerables.

If you want `...do some code...` to be executed when the enumerator is enumerated, then you'll need to use the `foreach`/`yield` loop to get the deferred execution semantics:

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<string> MyFunction()
{
 // ...do some code...

 // Return all elements of the whole stream from the enumerator
 await foreach(var s in MyStringEnumerator())
   yield return s;
}
```

And you would have to use the same pattern in the synchronous world if you wanted deferred execution semantics with a synchronous enumerable, too:

```
IEnumerable<string> ImmediateExecution()
{
 // ...do some code...

 // Return all elements of the whole stream from the enumerator
 return MyStringEnumerator();
}

IEnumerable<string> DeferredExecution()
{
 // ...do some code...

 // Return all elements of the whole stream from the enumerator
 foreach(var s in MyStringEnumerator())
   yield return s;
}
```

Comment: Will cancellation token semantics and using EnumeratorCancellation attribute work correctly with both immediate and deferred options?  Perhaps examples above could be expanded to show this?

Comment: @YevgeniyP: A more real-world solution would take `[EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken` and pass it through.

Answer (score 2):

Returning `Task<IAsyncEnumerable<Obj>>` from the calling method seems to work

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<string> MyStringEnumerator();

async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<string>> MyFunction()
{
    await Something();

    return MyStringEnumerator();
}
```

You'll then need to await MyFunction(). So to use in an async foreach would be

```
await foreach (string s in await MyFunction()) {}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for! Thanks.